# Can ORM sequelize have polymorphism?

Tags: orm

I have a model named User. Can I extend another model Admin/mod from User model? I have found the sequelize doc, but i didn't find out

Comment: It's not truly supported at this time, but there are some ways to do similar constructs using Sequelize. The main discussion can be found at: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1307

Answer (score 5):

Yes, check out the [Associations documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/scopes/#associations), or more fully in [Scopes documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#scopes).

From the docs:

```
this.Comment = this.sequelize.define('comment', {
  title: Sequelize.STRING,
  commentable: Sequelize.STRING,
  commentable_id: Sequelize.INTEGER
});

this.Comment.prototype.getItem = function() {
  return this['get' + this.get('commentable').substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + this.get('commentable').substr(1)]();
};

this.Post.hasMany(this.Comment, {
  foreignKey: 'commentable_id',
  constraints: false,
  scope: {
    commentable: 'post'
  }
});
this.Comment.belongsTo(this.Post, {
  foreignKey: 'commentable_id',
  constraints: false,
  as: 'post'
});

this.Image.hasMany(this.Comment, {
  foreignKey: 'commentable_id',
  constraints: false,
  scope: {
    commentable: 'image'
  }
});
this.Comment.belongsTo(this.Image, {
  foreignKey: 'commentable_id',
  constraints: false,
  as: 'image'
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to get 'commentable' data(e.g. row data of Post or Image) using Commentable.find() function?

Comment: How can onCascade and onDelete functions be implemented in models in this case?